# Convert string to float?

Tags: java

Just as title says. I don't believe it is possible to do this but if it is let me know.

This is needed for a bukkit (minecraft server) plugin I'm writing. I want to take a command: tnt [power]. Where power is the string returned that I want to convert to float.

Thanks

Comment: Read the Java API for float [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) You can construct a new float from a string.  There are also other ways to do it. Please use Google.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `Float.valueOf(String)` to do the conversion.

The difference between `valueOf()` and `parseFloat()` is only the return. Use the former if you want a `Float` (object) and the latter if you want the `float` number.

Answer (score 10):

Using [`Float.parseFloat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html)?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "3.14";
        float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "3.14";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String numberStr = "3.5";
Float number = null;
try {
   number = Float.parseFloat(numberStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("numberStr is not a number");
}
```

Comment: The try/catch is pretty essential.  Try it with bad data to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NumberFormatExceptionExample {
private static final String str = "123.234";
public static void main(String[] args){
float i = Float.valueOf(str); //Float.parseFloat(str);
System.out.println("Value parsed :"+i);
}
}
```

This should resolve the problem.

Can anyone suggest how should we handle this when the string comes in 35,000.00

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String yourVal = "20.5";
float a = (Float.valueOf(yourVal)).floatValue(); 
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

The easyest way is:

```
///Groovy/////
String a = "23.5";
Float b = a.toFloat();

////Java////
String a = "23.5";
float b = Float.valueOf(a);
```

Comment: What language are you using? It isn't java.

Comment: Excuse me that language is in groovy, i edit to work in java