# Converting String To Float number in android

Tags: android, string, data-conversion

```
String number="3";
```

Using:

```
Float f=Float.parseFloat(number);`
```

is giving error.

How can I convert it into `float`?

Code:

```
 `JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("response2");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)

                 jsonObject=jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                String three=jsonObject.optString("3.0");
                float f = Float.parseFloat(three);

             String  v1e1 = new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(three), 0); // 0

            `
```

Error:
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
                                                                                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705017/convert-string-to-float)

Comment: `giving error.` which error?

Comment: please share the error

Comment: @SagarGangawane I am getting response from server, so cannot enter static value.

Comment: @vishal.s paste your code so that we can help you.

Comment: is my code working @vishal.s ?

Comment: your three string variable contains empty string. that is the error says

Comment: @Ahamed  three contains a value 3. I can simply print it using system.out

Comment: @W4R10CK nops again getting same error.

Comment: It's problem with Json parsing. Not on string to float

Answer (score 1):

```
String number="3";
Float f = Float.valueOf(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should catch `NumberFormatException` in case of floating number conversion failures.

```
  try{
        String number="3";
        Float f=Float.parseFloat(number);
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException NFE)
      {
          System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + NFE.getMessage());
      }
```