# How to convert String to primitive float without losing decimal points

Tags: java

I need to convert String to primitive float without losing decimal points.

Ex : `String s = "11.50";` need to be converted as primitive float as `11.50f` without losing decimal points in Java. Any help is appreciated. I want only float only. Its not for printing purpose. Its to store in DB.

Comment: If you are converting it to float, why do you need the trailing zero? It's the same number without it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705017/convert-string-to-float)

Comment: A float number is a _number._  It does not have a number of trailing decimals.  As far as Java is concerned, `11.5` and `11.50` are exactly the same.  Java will not save the extra zero.  There is no way to make it save the extra zero.

Answer (score 1):

`Float.parseFloat(String)` or `Float.valueOf(String)` can be used here.

But `Float.parseFloat(String)` is recommended because it returns a primitive `float` but `Float.valueOf` returns a `Float` object.

FYI, if you need exact precision while monetary calculations we should not use `float` or `double` either in place of that we should use `BigDecimal`.